# How to view inline diff of multiple files at once in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff, vscode-extensions

In VS Code, for a given commit I would like to see inline diffs from all files in one view or page, so that I would not have to click to see diffs for each file separately.
I can't find any extension that would do this.

Basically I'm looking for a feature like there is in Bitbucket when you click on a given commit, and you see all the differences in one page. Something like in the picture below.

[image: bitbucket diff view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was, as commented, [posted on the GitLens issue-tracker](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/404); one commenter appears to have gotten fed-up, and created a separate extension for exactly this purpose.

You need a pair of two:

- [Whole Diff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacekKopecky.whole-diff), by Jacek Kopecký
- [Diff Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caponetto.vscode-diff-viewer), by Guilherme Caponetto

Then you get a nice single-click button that produces something like this:

[image: screenshot of vscode showing a visual side-by-side diff just like on GitHub]

Comment: If anyone want the diff to be side by side as in the image do the followings:
1) go to vs code settings.
2) search for outputFormat
3) set it to side-by-side

Answer (score 2):

VSCode happily supports this starting in January 2024 (version 1.86). See
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86#_review-multiple-files-in-diff-editor.

Note the `...` menu with the "Inline View" toggle item seems to be missing though for "multi diff". So to get inline view you need to add   `"diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false` to your settings.

Answer (score 1):

in the SCM bar you have a `COMMITS` view

- context click a commit and `Select for Compare`
- context click another commit and `Compare with Selected`

Now in `SEARCH & COMPARE` view you can click a changed file and see a diff

Comment: This unfortunately opens each file in its own editor tab. The question was how to "see all the differences in one page". I would love to see such a feature as well.

Comment: @carlfriedrich Not in its own tab, the tab is reused if you click a different file, at least with my settings, Create an issue if it is not implemented yet

Comment: @rioV8 - yes, the tab is reused in this scenario, but still you can view the diff for only one file at a time. I would like to view diff in all files at once, just by scrolling, like it is displayed in the screenshot from bitbucket

Comment: Temporary workarounds I found, but still not the exact feature I request.  

- Both in SEARCH & COMPARE and COMMITS view, I can use arrows and Space/Enter to select next file in the diff  

- In SEARCH & COMPARE when clicking Ahead or Behind, there's a globe icon () which opens the comparison on remote in the format I want (works on Bitbucket and Github). Similarly there's a globe icon for each commit in COMMITS view. Works only for pushed changes.

Comment: @Danny Have you checked whether there's an open issue on Git Lens? Maybe it's worth opening one: https://github.com/Axosoft/vscode-gitlens/issues